# Is it time to get a new Github account?

Tags: windows, git, bash, github

I got my Github account last year in February and configured it on my Windows XP. Successfully configured `user.name` and global email account. I switched operating system to Windows 8 and accessed the same Github account online.

I took the Try Git course and other supporting materials to start working with the repositories, but Git Bash keeps coming up with the invalid username and password login error on Bash. Completed the forking and would like to start working on a cloned `.git` template now, but I can't pass the error message.

I tried changing my username, which solved the error partially. On my local repositories list the newly forked folders are not found, and I'm not seeing any guides on how to use Git Shell on the website.

Any ideas on whether this is just a system setup error or is it time to get a new Github account?

Comment: why would a new github account fix anything? There's plenty of instructions online for using git shell. IMO you should focus on the root issue, fixing your git bash configuration.

Comment: Since nobody seems to know what seems to be the problem, I figured starting clean would eliminate the confusion all together.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your git config using `git config --list`. If it differs from what your are using then change it with `git config user.name YOUR_USERNAME` and `git config user.email YOUR_EMAIL`. More info [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup).

Comment: You're right. I checked the configuration and they do differ from the previous setting (from last February). Other than the invalid message, I am also getting public key error message when generating SSH key.

Comment: OK, it's auth then. Then check `git remote -v show`. If it something like _origin git@github.com:someuser/repo.git_ then you are using SSH key(HTTPS would ask password everytime you connect to github). Check then [this Github guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) to configure your SSH keys.

Comment: Ok thanks. The link and examples are useful. I just have to remember that the passwords are not the SSH keys and can be left blank.

Answer (score 0):

What you configure as `user.name` and `user.email` is what goes into the author and committer fields of commits you create.  It has nothing to do with authentication.